# Unable to build ANN with neuralnet

Tags: r

I tried building an artificial neural network using `neuralnet`, but got following error message:

```
nn <- neuralnet(Classs ~ . , s23, hidden=10, threshold=0.01)
```

> Error in terms.formula(formula) : '.' in formula and no 'data' argument

Could someone explain this error message to me? This is my code:

```
library(neuralnet)
s23<-read.csv("E:/Research/SEM6/classification/breastcancer.csv")
s23
nn <- neuralnet(Classs ~ . , s23, hidden=10, threshold=0.01)
names(nn)
nn$result.matrix
plot(nn)
```

Comment: If you pay attention to the error message, it says that there is no `data` argument. Your first thought to fix this could be *"what arguments does `neuralnet` require, and what do they mean?"* To answer this, consider reading the documentation for the function, freely and easily available with `?neuralnet`. Regardless, using a formula in a function such as this will *always* require a `data` argument. (Oh, and perhaps you should learn the distinction between *positional arguments* and (relevant here) *named arguments*.)

Comment: I do believe that i am writting the code according to the syntax.

Comment: Ok, can you show us some of the data? Perhaps `dput(head(s23))` would be enough.

Comment: (BTW: sorry, your code does look right, not certain what I saw when I wrote the first comment ...)

Comment: i am using a breast cancer dataset with 11 variables and 699 observations from UCI.

Comment: You really need to provide more information if you want to get more help. I did a little research and found [this](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Breast+Cancer+Wisconsin+%28Original%29), I'm assuming that this is your data. In the future, provide **both** a sample of the data *and* a link to the site so that helpers can look more. Looking at the code and error, I suggest (esp since the code hasn't been adjusted since 2012) that it's a bug in `neuralnet:::varify.variables` and its call to `terms(formula)` (should be `terms(formula,data)`?).